# How to pass a column value from FOR LOOP to select into query using ORACLE?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to pass the value from For loop into Select into query. But it is failing to pass the value. Instead it shows the string as such. Below is my look alike query.

```
DECLARE

filters  VARCHAR2(4000);

BEGIN

    FOR SRC IN (SELECT ABC , EFG , HIJ ,KLM FROM table_name WHERE rownum < 2)

    LOOP

    FILTERs := '';

    FOR con IN (SELECT DISTINCT cols.column_name AS COL FROM all_constraints cons, all_cons_columns cols
                WHERE cols.table_name = table_name
                AND cons.constraint_type = 'P'
                AND cons.constraint_name = cols.constraint_name
                AND cons.owner = OWNER_NAME)                
    LOOP

    select filters || con.col || ' = ''''''|| SRC.' ||con.col||'||'''''' AND ' INTO filters FROM dual;

    END LOOP;   

    dbms_output.put_line(Filters);

    END LOOP;
END;
```

The output I get is:

```
ABC = '''|| SRC.ABC||''' AND EFG = '''|| SRC.EFG||''' AND
```

But what I expect is:

```
ABC = '1234' AND EFG = '5678' AND
```

How can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

This code block worked for me. You have to use dynamic SQL here.

Sample data:

```
create table table_name(abc, efg, hij, klm) as (
    select '1234', '5678', 'PQR', 'XYZ' from dual union all
    select '1221', '8688', 'ABQ', 'ZAA' from dual 
    );
alter table table_name add constraint tn_pk primary key (abc, efg);
```

Code block:

```
declare
  v_flt varchar2(4000);
  v_val varchar2(1000);
  v_sql varchar2(4000);
begin
  for r in (select rowid rwd from table_name where rownum <= 2) loop
      v_flt := '';
      for con in (select column_name col
                    from all_constraints  cons
                    join all_cons_columns cols using (owner, table_name, constraint_name)
                    where owner = 'SCOTT' 
                      and table_name = 'TABLE_NAME' 
                      and constraint_type = 'P') 
      loop
        v_sql := 'select '||con.col||' from table_name where rowid = '''||r.rwd||'''' ;
        execute immediate v_sql into v_val;
        v_flt := v_flt ||con.col||' = '''||v_val||''' AND ';
      end loop;
      dbms_output.put_line(v_flt);
  end loop;
end;
```

Result:

```
ABC = '1221' AND EFG = '8688' AND 
ABC = '1234' AND EFG = '5678' AND
```

Comment: Thanks alot !!  It helped me half way. But why it can print only one row though we have given rownum <=2.  It throws error " no data found " after printing one row though the table has rows to loop .I dint modify anything in your code except tablename and owner. Iam i missing anything ?

Comment: No idea. If you are able to provide reproducible example (data and your exact code) we can help. In my example you can loop through one, two, all rows.